# "on weekdays", "on weekday" or "on the weekday"

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Is "on the weekday" an idiomatic phrase in English to refer to many weekdays? Or is it grammatically incorrect and it should be "on weekdays"?

For example,

Jack visits that club on the weekday.

Comment: "the" is always specific. Jack visits the club **on the weekday** his wife proposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual phrase in "on weekdays".

"on the weekdays" could only be correct in certain contexts; i.e. if the weekdays have been specified, but generally speaking, people don't say "on the weekdays" unless the context calls for it, which is rare.

Comment: Thank you. What about "on the weekday"?

Comment: You're welcome. I can't imagine any context in which "on the weekday" is a phrase I would ever use as a stand-alone phrase, but I can think of a sentence in which it is plausible (but not as a stand-alone phrase): A: I go to the library on Mondays. B: Don't you go to the library on Fridays? A: No, I just go there on the weekday (that) I said.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have actually misheard, or misread the likely alternatives. You asked about the following two phrases:

- on ***the*** weekday
- on weekdays

but my guess is that you are more likely to have read these two:

- on ***a*** weekday
- on weekdays

"On the weekday" does not sound to me like native English usage. However, the expressions "on a weekday" or "on weekdays" are both heard frequently. "On a weekday" is used when something is probably going to happen on a single occasion. For example, if were to go to a shop on Saturday or Sunday and found it closed, someone might say to you, "I suggest that you go again on ***strong text***a weekday". The implication is that you will probably only want to go once and that a weekday is the right time to go. On the other hand, you might see a sign on the door of the shop that said "Open on weekdays" ... meaning that it is open every weekday.

Comment: On the weekday could be use when there is a choice: I'm not going on the Sunday you mention. I'm going on the weekday he mentioned.